# My divs are bleeding when they shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, css, html

So, I'm working on this JSFIDDLE (http://jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/248/) and I can't see why botcontainer div is bleeding into the footer. Other pages that I've created on the site don't have this problem.

I think it has to do with a recently JS coded div hide/reveal on the "vertical Expertise" tiles because I've checked all of the divs and made certain they're all closed. Also, tried display and position edits that had no effect.

Here's the basics of the CSS for content containers::

```
#topcontainer {
margin:75px 0 0 0;
}

#botcontainer {
margin:100px 0 0 0;
}
```

Here's the basic css for the "vertical expertise" area (which is wrapped in the botcontainer div)::

```
.vertTiles {
border: none; 
margin-right: 3px;
margin-top:3px;
float:left;
}
.vertCont {
border: 1px solid black; 
background-color: #ffffff; 
display: none;
padding: 5px; 
width:800px;
max-width:800px;
height:400px;
max-height:400px;
top:0;
left:0;
}
#xbox {
position:absolute;
width:75px;
height:75px;
bottom:20px;
right:20px;
}
```

Note that I've left out the MM_imageswap js just keep things clean in JSFIDDLE. ANy help from the community would be helpful!

Comment: You mean `#content { overflow: hidden; }` ?

Comment: @sabof I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not looking to hide content beyond the vertCont class. I want the vertical expertise section to NOT bleed into the footer area.

Comment: Try adding it to the fiddle, and you'll see what it does. The content won't be hidden.

Comment: @sabof I see what you mean! Thanks! That works. Solution is: overflow:hidden on #botcontainer.

Comment: @Shadna, did you take a look at my fiddle? its the same that sabof suggested with a slight variation

Answer (score 2):

Your code and CSS styles are Vast. It will take some time to go through it.
This is what i added. Is this what u want? Your question is a bit confusing.

CSS

```
#botcontainer {
    margin:100px 0 0 0;
    clear:both;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/249/)